# wordpress - how to display the results of wp_list_authors in a dropdown menu

Tags: wordpress

Would like to display the results of wp_list_authors in a dropdown menu

Not sure how to do this.

edited to add - is it possible to use feed the results of wp_list_authors to wp_dropdown_users ?

Answer (score 1):

That's built into wp_dropdown_users, just use the 'who' argument.

```
<?php wp_dropdown_users(array('who'=>'authors')); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_users